# Base-from-Member Idiom in C++

Tags: c++, idioms, ostream, initialization-list

The following code is from [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member):

```
#include <streambuf>  // for std::streambuf
#include <ostream>    // for std::ostream

class fdoutbuf
    : public std::streambuf
{
public:
    explicit fdoutbuf( int fd );
    //...
};

class fdostream
    : public std::ostream
{
protected:
    fdoutbuf buf;
public:
    explicit fdostream( int fd ) 
        : buf( fd ), std::ostream( &buf ) // This is not allowed. 
                                          // buf can't be initialized before std::ostream.
        {}
    //...
};
```

I didn't really understand the comment. Why *"buf can't be initialized before std::ostream"*? Can I use some help understanding this?

Comment: actually that code is totally ok, as long as the base class constructor (in this case `std::ostream(std::streambuf* buf_ptr)` does not access the buf object (aka `*buf_ptr)`. `&buf` does correctly point to the memory address where `buf` will be constructed later on, since the `this` pointer is already valid in the member-initializer-list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order of initialization is determined by the order of declaring your class members, and inherited classes come before all of that. Take a simple example that illustrate the basic problem without referring to inheritance :

```
class C
{
  int a, b;
public:
  C() : b(1), a(b) {} // a is initialized before b!
};
```

The code doesn't do what you think! a is initialized first, then b is initialized to one. So it depends on the order of the declaration not the order in the initialization list:

```
int a, b;
```

Now, the same idea applies to base classes which are initialized before the derived class members. To solve this problem, you create a class that you inherent which contains the member you want to initialize from a base class. Of course, that helper class must come before the one you are actually deriving from.

Answer (score 3):

You have to call the base class constructor before you initialize your member variables, but you pass a pointer to buf (a member variable which is undefined at this point) to this constructor.

Comment: its a `pointer to a member variable`, not a `member variable`, that makes quite a difference.. see my comment above. "you have to call the base class constructor first" is kinda wrong, since not you but the language does that.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the thing with the pointer. Bur I think your second point is just about wording because you have to put the call (or however you name it) to the constructor in there anyway (because it expects a parameter) and I would consider the code to be wrong if it was put in the wrong order, even if it would be technically correct - Readability is key :-)